# Improve SQL query to calculate timespan between two consecutive rows

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, timespan

So... I have a a table like this:

```
RowID | DocID | Time       | DepartmentID
1     | 1001  | 2015-11-20 | 1
2     | 1001  | 2015-11-21 | 2
3     | 1002  | 2015-11-20 | 1
4     | 1001  | 2015-11-25 | 1
5     | 1002  | 2015-11-22 | 3
6     | 1002  | 2015-11-30 | 1
```

My goal is to get the time in days a department spends with a document before sending it to another department.

I successfully achieved this by passing above table from SQL to a datatable in C#. Then get list of DocsID, and iterate throw each item in that list filtering the datatable with DocID and only then calculate the time between consecutive rows.
So the final result looks like:

```
DepartmentID | DocID | Time (Days)
1            | 1001  | 2
2            | 1001  | 5
1            | 1002  | 3
3            | 1002  | 9
```

The problem is this function in C# is taking about 30 seconds to get this results, so I'm looking for ways to improve it.
Is it possible to get this throw SQL only without making anything in C#?

My C# function (dt is a datatable with first table):

```
        List<Int32> listDocIDs = new List<Int32>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int str = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DocID"].ToString());

            if (!listDocIDs.Contains(str))
                listDocIDs.Add(str);
        }

        DataTable times = new DataTable();

        times.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("DepartmentID", typeof(Int32)),
                        new DataColumn("DocID",typeof(Int32)),
                        new DataColumn("Days",typeof(Int32)) });

        foreach (int DocID in listDocIDs)
        {
            DataTable DocID_times = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("getRecordsByDocID", conn);
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DocID;
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.Fill(DocID_times);
                conn.Close();
            }

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < DocID_times.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                j = i + 1;

                if (i < (DocID_times.Rows.Count - 1))
                {
                    DateTime tempo1 = DateTime.ParseExact(DocID_times.Rows[i]["Time"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime tempo2 = DateTime.ParseExact(DocID_times.Rows[j]["Time"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    double mins = (tempo2 - tempo1).TotalMinutes;
                    TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mins);
                    double days = result.TotalDays;

                    var rows = times.Select(string.Format("DepartmentID = {0} AND DocID = {1}", DepartmentID, DocID));
                    if (rows.Length == 0)
                    {
                        // Add your Row
                        times.Rows.Add(DepartmentID, DocID, days);     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Update your Days
                        rows[0]["days"] = Convert.ToInt32(rows[0]["days"].ToString()) + days;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: question is unclear. I think its a search algorithm problem. Please show what query you are using. You only show input and output. Please show you what you do with input to get this output.

Comment: How do you know your SQL query is taking more time? may be your c# function is taking more but not the query? May be you have some kind of nested loop in your code which is taking more time? Please post C# code as well as SQL query.........

Comment: I reviewed my question, it's more clear now? What is taking time is the function I built in C# to get from input to output.

Comment: [Quote @Viru] "Please post C# code as well as SQL query"

Comment: just posted the C# function. SQL query is just "select * from" so don't think that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're listing all the rows, I would calculate the days between records inside a while loop. It can be done purely with SQL, but it won't be as good as the while loop (which can have access to two rows at a time). To be able to do it purely in SQL, you would have to join the table with itself, joining each record with the next one.

```
IEnumerable<MySummarizedRow> GetSummarizedRows()
{
    using (var entries = GetRowsOrderedByDocIdAndRowId().GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (entries.MoveNext())
        {
            var previous = entries.Current;
            while (entries.MoveNext())
            {
                var current = entries.Current;
                if (current.DocId == previous.DocId)
                    yield return new MySummarizedRow(previous.DepartmentId, current.DocId, current.Time.Substract(previous.Time).TotalDays + 1);

                previous = current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function ignores the rows for a document that hasn't been passed to another department yet. You can easily change that yielding a new row with -1 days or something like that.